# Equivalente ao método .filter() da jQuery ou Zepto em javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer o método "filter" como o da jQuery ou Zepto em javascript puro?

Eu quero implementar esse método na minha biblioteca: https://github.com/acauamontiel/mantis-js/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L3

#### HTML

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p class="middle">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p class="middle">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

#### JS

```
$('p').filter('.middle'); // Retorna somente o "p" que tiver a classe "middle"
```

Comment: confira minha nova resposta editada, acho que é o que você quer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso do seu exemplo, nem seria necessário o `filter`. Dá para resolver com um único seletor:

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('p.middle');
```

Uma maneira simples de implementar o `filter` é pegar dois conjuntos de elementos, e comparar todos com todos. Certamente existem maneiras mais eficientes de se implementar a função, mas esta é bem didática:

```
function filter(selElementos, selFiltro) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selElementos);
    var filtro = document.querySelectorAll(selFiltro);
    var saida = [];
    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<filtro.length; j++) {
            if(els[i] == filtro[j]) {
                saida.push(els[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return saida;
}
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BR5rY/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## Explicação:

Utilizando Javascript puro você teria que percorrer no seu Documento todos os elementos que tenham a tag `<p>` utilizando a função `document.getElementsByTagName()`, e então armazena-los num Array para facil iteração entre eles e então utilizar de um laço de repetição para verificar se cada um deles possui a classe `middle` ou não, e armazena-los em outro array apenas os que tiverem, e depois você tera o Array que você poderá ver no console com apenas os elementos que possuem classe Middle, como um `HTMLCollection` que nada mais é do que um Array de Elementos HTML.

## Solução:

Código Javascript:

```js
function filter(tagName,classe){
    var aryP = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var len  = aryP.length;
    var aryPMiddle = [];
    for (var i=0;i < len; i++){
        if (aryP[i].getAttribute('class') == classe){
          aryPMiddle.push(aryP[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(aryPMiddle);
    return aryPMiddle;
}
```

Então basta executar a função:

```js
filter('p','middle');
```

E você terá o retorno de:

```html
[p.middle, p.middle]
```

## [Exemplo funcional no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74tDP/1/)

## **-- EDIT --**

Porém você quer um uso parecido com a `.filter()` do jQuery em mais aspectos, alem de pegar todos os elementos com a tag fornecida, então sugiro utilizar esta função que você pode mandar um seletor qualquer para ela da mesma forma que voce utiliza no jQuery:

```
function filter(selector){
    var aryPMiddle = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.log(aryPMiddle);
    return aryPMiddle;
}
```

## Exemplo de uso:

Com o seguinte HTML:

```
<p id="middle">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p class="middle">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p class="middle">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Executando:

```
filter('.middle');
```

Retornaria:

> NodeList[p.middle, p.middle]

E executando:

```
filter('#middle');
```

Retornaria:

> NodeList[p#middle]

Nota: infelizmente no JSFiddle não funcionou e o motivo ainda é desconhecido, porém se você executar no console de seu navegador funciona corretamente.

Comment: Paulo, obrigado pela resposta, mas o código que passei acima foi apenas exemplo de uma das funcionalidades do método `.filter()` original.
Também teria que filtrar por ID's, atributos e aceitar uma função como parâmetro, mas a parte da função eu já sei como implementar.
Minha maior dúvida é _filtrar_ os elementos previamente selecionados pelo meu método `$()`, ou seja, já tenho um array de elementos, mas não sei se filtrar cada parte do seletor (por regex, por exemplo) seria a melhor opção.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cls = 'middle';
var tag = 'P';

var lista = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++)
{
    if ((' ' + lista[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1)
    {
        // tratar o elemento com a classe
    }
}
```

Comment: Miguel, obrigado pela resposta, mas o código que passei acima contém apenas uma das funcionalidades do método `.filter()` original. Pretendo fazer um método equivalente em todas as funcionalidades do _filter_ da jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/filter/